# Re-insert modified object EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have strange behavior,

Using entityframwork 6 i retrieve list of objects, then i modify a foreign key then insert the list again. however the result is that the insertion is done but the foreign key is not modified.

```
 var clients = Uow.Clients.GetAll().where(x => x.zipCode= newZip);
            var newClients = new List<Client>();
            foreach (var client in clients)
            {
                client.City = null;
                client.cityId = newCityId;
                newClients.Add(client);
            }
            Uow.Clients.AddMany(newClients);
            Uow.Commit();
```

if you wondering if i saveChanges or if AddMany works, the answer is yes, i use these functions alot and all works fine.

Comment: When you debug the `newClients` records, each `cityId` is what it is in `clients` and not what you explicitly set it to? Is it a valid foreign key?

Comment: You're never using `newClients` after populating it.  I don't see how this would work at all.

Comment: You adding new entities - Its 1st problem. Why you are creating `newClients` and not use? `T.City` can be nullable?

Comment: sorry typo mistake newclients is the one that is added

Answer (score 1):

What may be happening is that when you perform the search, your entities are linked to the context through `DbContext`'s `ChangeTracker`, try to make the search disconnected from DbContext using `AsNoTracking()` and then modify the data. Try this:

```
var clients = Uow.Clients.AsNoTracking().where(x => x.zipCode= newZip);
var newClients = new List<Client>();
foreach (var client in clients)
{
    client.City = null;
    client.cityId = newCityId;
    newClients.Add(client);
}

Uow.Clients.AddMany(client);
Uow.Commit();
```

PS: I'm deducing that Uow is a DbContext object